# Java annotations for field

Tags: java, аннотации, field

Мне нужно аннотировать поле, которое используется в разных классах. Как можно аннотировать его так, чтобы в одном классе возвращалось его значение, а во всех других классах это поле было бы пустым? Можно ли это вообще сделать с помощью аннотации? (проверку поля на аннотацию методом isPresentAnnotation не представляется возможным)

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса и непонятно зачем писать его на английском.

Comment: Суть вопроса такова: можно ли как-нибудь с помощью аннотаций, аннотировать поле так, чтобы при вызове в одном классе поле возвращало свое значение, а при вызове его же из других классов было пустым. Проверить в данных классах поле на isPresentAnnotation не представляется возможным.

Comment: Во-первых, вам стоит таки отредактировать свой вопрос, так как иначе его закроют. Во-вторых, доступ к полям должен осуществляться через акссесоры, а значит ничто не мешает вам сделать поле приватным, а из соответствующего геттера возвращать `null`.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, вопрос отредактировал. Про вторую часть, не совсем понял. Поле возможно сделать приватным через аннотацию?

Comment: Нет, поле можно (и нужно) просто сделать приватным, без аннотаций.

Comment: Наверное не совсем корректно задал вопрос. Я хочу аннотацией пометить поле как "дополнительное", чтобы в основном классе поле возвращало значение, а при построении "дополнительных" вещей, это поле возвращало бы null

Comment: Правильно-ли понял, вы хотите, чтобы в базовом классе геттер на это поле возвращал значение, а в классах наследниках возвращал null?

Comment: Да, хотя бы что-то вроде такой логики

Comment: Что-то вроде `public String getValue() {
        return this.getClass() == A.class ? this.value : "";
    }` при вызове из класса A вернет значение value, а если вызвать у наследников - пустую строку